# Validate token without login multiple times

Tags: jmeter

In my script I am performing two steps,

Step 1: Login to the application
Step 2: Validate the coupon code from the CSV file.

Problem Statement: When I enter the coupon code on the URL it return me the following value, I want if the coupon code return me invalid then it should validate the next coupon code without switching back to login again.

```
{"Valid"} for Valid Token Code
{"InValid"} for Invalid Token Code
```

Test Plan:

[image]

CSV File:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move your [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to be a child of the `Validate Coupon Code` request. Amend [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy) settings according to your test scenario
2. Put your `Generate Bearer Token` under the [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller), this way it will be executed only once per thread (virtual user), during the first iteration of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and will be skipped for the subsequent iterations